# Error on Acumatica Create Code File for New DAC based on database table

Tags: acumatica

[CreatingCodeFileForNewDACFromDatabaseTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNR36.png)

I am trying to add a new DAC from an existing database table per the Acumatica documentation.  However, when I click OK, I get an error:

localhost says "An unhandled exception has occurred in function MoveNext.  Please see the trace log for more details.

Anyone seen this before?  How should I proceed?  Where are the trace logs stored?

Thanks,

David

Comment: see link for image of the screen in Acumatica where I am attempting to create the new DAC

Answer (score 0):

The issue only happens if there is no ItemDocument table in your database.

If you've just created ItemDocument table, make sure to restart IIS or recycle app pool to make sure Acumatica is aware of the new table, as it caches database schema once, when domain starts.

When you create new DAC in the Customization Manager, its namespace will match name of the customization project:
[image]
It's necessary to type FullName of a custom DAC (inc. namespace) when using a custom DAC inside different namespace - ***DocCenter.ItemBaseDocumen‌​t*** in your case:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(S‌​earch<DocCenter.ItemBaseDocumen‌​t.baseDocumentCode, 
     OrderBy<Asc<DocCenter.ItemBase‌​Document.BaseDocument‌​Code>>>), 
 DescriptionField = typeof(DocCenter.ItemBaseDocum‌​ent.baseDocumentShort‌​Description))]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to get it to work after restarting IIS.

Comment: Unfortunately, now the PXSelector code doesnt recognize the DAC.

Comment: namespace DocCenter
{
  [Serializable]
  public class ItemBaseDocument: IBqlTable
  {
    

    #region BaseDocumentCode

    [PXDBString(60, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Base Document Code")]
    public string BaseDocumentCode { get; set; }

    public class baseDocumentCode : IBqlField{}

    #endregion

Comment: [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentCode,
OrderBy<Asc<ItemBaseDocument.BaseDocumentCode>>>),
DescriptionField = typeof(ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentShortDescription))]

Comment: Building directory '/WebSiteValidationDomain/App_RuntimeCode/'.
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ItemBaseDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ItemBaseDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Since I added the new DAC for the ItemBaseDocument class related to the custom database table, why am I getting an error about the namespace not being found?

Comment: Am I missing another step that needs to occur in order to be able to reference the ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentCode value in the PXSelector for the UsrDocumentNumber?